# How to position a div object to the very left edge of the screen?

Tags: html, css, position, embed

Here is the code and current result:

```css
div.paragraph
{
padding: 30px 25%;
}

div.tableauPlaceholder
{
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='paragraph'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae.</p>

<p>Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Quis risus sed vulputate odio. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus.</p>

<p>Vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id. Purus semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis. In aliquam sem fringilla ut. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet.</p>

<p>Euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Morbi non arcu risus quis. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Dolor purus non enim praesent. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac.</p>

<p>Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam. In est ante in nibh mauris. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa.</p>

<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1591849948271' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Br&#47;BrianDennehy&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='BrianDennehy&#47;Dashboard1' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Br&#47;BrianDennehy&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='filter' value='mobile=' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1591849948271');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='1700px';vizElement.style.height='727px';} else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='1700px';vizElement.style.height='727px';} else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1577px';}                     var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae.</p>

<p>Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Quis risus sed vulputate odio. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus.</p>

<p>Euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Morbi non arcu risus quis. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Dolor purus non enim praesent. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac.</p>
</div>
```

Here is desired output:
[image: Object follows parent padding]

The problem is that the embedded object follows the parent padding. My attempt at doing negative padding did not work. So I tried doing:

```
div.tableauPlaceholder
{
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
}
```

I asked a similar question not too long ago and got transform:translatex(-XX) as a potential solution, but I'm not too keen on doing that for every single embedded objects later.

What other methods can I try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the object to stay on very left of screen replace our css with this

```
div.tableauPlaceholder
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

It would be helpful if you give a width to that no other object overflows the tableauPlaceholder.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do the following change in the CSS:

```css
.paragraph
{
padding: 30px 0px;
}

.tableauPlaceholder
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

p
{
margin: 0% 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class='paragraph'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae.</p>

<p>Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Quis risus sed vulputate odio. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus.</p>

<p>Vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id. Purus semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis. In aliquam sem fringilla ut. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet.</p>

<p>Euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Morbi non arcu risus quis. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Dolor purus non enim praesent. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac.</p>

<p>Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam. In est ante in nibh mauris. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa.</p>

<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1591849948271'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Br&#47;BrianDennehy&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='BrianDennehy&#47;Dashboard1' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Br&#47;BrianDennehy&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='filter' value='mobile=' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1591849948271');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='1700px';vizElement.style.height='727px';} else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='1700px';vizElement.style.height='727px';} else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1577px';}                     var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae.</p>

<p>Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Quis risus sed vulputate odio. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus.</p>

<p>Euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Morbi non arcu risus quis. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Dolor purus non enim praesent. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac.</p>
</div>
```

Because your tableau chart is inside the paragraph div, `position: absolute` only affects the parent element and not the body or general page. The only option is to set a specific padding for the `p` tag itself

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute will not work here until you give it `!important` because I checked your code in fiddle and the `tableauPlaceholder` has an inline property of `position:relative;` also to align it to extreme left give it `left:0;` note: you also need to set position of parent div `paragraph` to `relative`

So you can try something like this

```
div.paragraph
{
    padding: 30px 25%;
    position:relative;
}

div.tableauPlaceholder
{
  position: absolute !important;
  left:0;
}
```

Without using `position:absolute;` to adjust the `tableauPlaceholder` as setting its position absolute will shift the content below this div under it.

So you can try something like this:-

```
div.paragraph
{
    padding: 30px 0;
    position:relative;
}
div.paragraph p{
    padding:0 25%;
}

div.tableauPlaceholder
{
    position:relative;
}
```

Also set the width of `tableauPlaceholder` less then its parent element as it currently overflowing the parent div

Comment: It works, but there is now overlap, text is pushed up and is hidden behind the embedded object. What can I do about this?

Comment: Then you can try something which @cote has suggested in his answer, but without using position absolute. I have edited my answer above to do it, please check and let me know if it works, Thanks